# JavaScript: Split array into groups (array of arrays) based on equal values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to do this exercise:

> The challenge is to implement a function which adds all together all
>   the consecutive numbers in an array and pushes them into a new array.
>   example: sumConsecutives([1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]);
>       `// -> [2,2,4,2,3]`

My idea is to split the array into an array of arrays. So for the above example: `[[1,1],[2],[1,1,1,1],[2],[1,1,1]]` then go through and `reduce` them.

I've tried with a `while` loop and `push` into a temp variable which then gets pushed if the next number is not the same, to no avail.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: You want us to do your homework? And please, share your code. We will help you fix bugs but we are not your code factory.

Comment: What have you achieved so far? Please paste your code snippet, if you have one, to help you improve it.

Comment: please bring the code into the studio

Comment: @Randy No. I asked for ideas on 'how to achieve this'. Did I ask you to write it out for me? Either way, code incoming

Comment: you only need one for-loop for this..

Comment: `var reducer = a => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => (i === 0 ? p[0] = c : c == a[i-1] ? p[p.length-1] += c : p[p.length] = c,p),[])`

Comment: @Redu I came up with quite a similar codegolf version ;) `a.reduce((p,c,i,a)=>(c===a[i-1]?p[p.length-1]+=c:p[p.length]=c,p),[])`

Comment: @pawel right for primitives `a[-1]` will return `undefined` and this works but if the array items were objects like {a:1} then it would result a "can not read property 'a' of undefined" error. I always care for a[-1] condition as a general precaution.

Comment: create output array, create currentItemValue run a loop over all items.. assign the current value to some currentSum variable.. and so on.. let your brain work a bit..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach I could think of... (without map/reduce, though)

```js
var sumConsecutives = function(arr) {
var newArr = [];
var prev = arr[0];
var sum = arr[0];

for (var i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
 if (arr[i] !== prev) {
  newArr[newArr.length] = sum;
  sum = 0;
 }
 sum += arr[i];
 prev = arr[i];
}

// Add last sum
newArr[newArr.length] = sum;

return newArr;
};

console.log ( sumConsecutives([1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a one step `reduce` approach:

```js
const sumConsecutives = ar =>
ar.reduce((ac, x, i) => {
  if ( i !== 0 && ar[i-1] === x)
    ac[ac.length -1] += x;
  else 
    ac.push(x);
    
  return ac;
 }, [])


var r = sumConsecutives([1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]); // -> [2,2,4,2,3]

console.log(r)
```

Comment: @Kreitzo I didn't actually understand if you want  to count the repeated instances of the duplicate following numbers or use their sum, if you want to change current behaviour look on line 4

Answer (score 1):

I liked the challange so I made it in a two-step function you thought was useful.

- The first reduce creates the array of arrays
- The second reduce sums them up.

It is not the shortest code, but I hope the most understandable.

```js
const arr = [1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1];
let currentNumber = undefined;
let currentTempArr = [];

let newArr = arr.reduce((tempArr, value) => {
  // check if current number is set
  if(currentNumber == undefined) currentNumber = value;
  
  // if current number then push to temp array
  if(currentNumber == value)
    currentTempArr.push(value);
  // else just create a new array and push the old one into the parent array
  else {
    tempArr.push(currentTempArr);
    currentTempArr = [];
    currentNumber = value;
    currentTempArr.push(value);
  }
  
  // return the array back to the next reduce iteration
  return tempArr;
}, []);

// push the last temp array, because the function stops before the push
newArr.push(currentTempArr);

// this build your array of arrays
console.info('The array of arrays');
console.log(newArr); // [ [1,1,1], [2], ... ]

// now sum up the sub arrays
let sumArr = newArr.reduce((tempArr, value) => {
  let sum = 0;
  
  // for every value in the array we add that to the sum
  value.forEach(val => sum += val);
  
  // add the total to the temp array
  tempArr.push(sum);
  
  // return the filled array back to the reduce function
  return tempArr;
}, []);

// the array with summed up values
console.info('see the magic happen');
console.log(sumArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sumConsecutives(input) {
    var output = [],
        factor = 1,
        lastnr = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            lastnr = input[i];
            continue;
        }

        if (input[i] !== lastnr) {
            output.push(lastnr * factor);
            lastnr = input[i];
            factor = 1;
        } else {
            factor++;
        }

        if (i === (input.length - 1)) {
            output.push(input[i] * factor);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

var result = sumConsecutives([1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.reduce`

#### Logic

- Create a temp array.
- loop over array and check if previous and current value.
- If same, take last element of temp array and add current value to it.
- If not, push current element to temp array

#### Sample

```js
function sumConsecutives(arr) {
  var r = [];
  arr.reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
    if (p === c) {
      r[r.length - 1] += c
    } else {
      r.push(c)
    }
    return c;
  }, 0);
  return r;
}
var a = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1];
console.log(sumConsecutives(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest i could think of:

```js
var testarr = [1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1];
var resultarr = [testarr[0]];
for(var i=1; i<testarr.length; i++){
 if(testarr[i-1]==testarr[i]){
  resultarr[resultarr.length - 1] += testarr[i];
 }else{
  resultarr.push(testarr[i]);
 }
}
console.log(resultarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this approach :

```
var source = [1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1];

source.reduce(function(p, c, index, arr) {                 
   if (p.length === 0 || arr[index - 1] !== c) {
       return p.concat(c);
   }
   else if (arr[index - 1] === c) {           
        p[p.length - 1] += c             
   }

   return p;
}, []);
```